# What's the relation between Java EE and Grails

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails

I'm taking a course named "Developing distributed application with JEE". They asked us to develop an application using Grails and Groovy. I'm a little confused, what's the relation between Java EE and Grails?

For me they are different frameworks like Django, Ruby on Rails...etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often people think of EJBs when they think of Java EE, but that's just one of several of the technologies used in Java EE. Grails supports or uses several Java EE technologies directly (including the Servlet API, JSPs, JSTL, transactions (JTA), JPA, etc.), and others are available via plugins (e.g. WebSockets, JMS, JAX-RS, etc.)

Grails uses Spring, so instead of using CDI for dependency injection, it uses Spring's DI support. Spring has excellent integration for many Java EE technologies, so using EJBs and other Java EE APIs would be straightforward by leveraging Spring for those.

Additionally, deploying a Grails application is the same as for any other servlet-based application - you create a WAR file and deploy it to a servlet container or application server. There are also scripts available to package a Grails application in an EAR file if necessary.

Comment: "Often people think of EJBs when they think of Java EE" - Indeed, I still hear that occasionally. In addition to what you said; it's not even that there are many other technologies in Java EE besides EJB, Java EE is even strongly deemphasizing EJB. For Java EE 8 there's no update for EJB planned, and EE 7 only saw a small update. It's not that EJB is complicated or bad, but the platform is refocussing on CDI based services.

Answer (score 0):

You can read on this link.Hope it will clear your confusion.

http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/10/14/Grails-new-J2EE-Paradigm

Comment: How? It mentions J2EE but doesn't go into any detail about how Grails uses it or where they're different.